# echo, each step, while, loop, activate

Tags: php, sql

hi guys (I'm relatively new and really just learning 12 hour per day!), - don't waste your time if I am too stupid.

However I will try to ask here anyway.

I have a php-loop that run through multiple id's (or rows) in a sql-table and `echo $something` from that specific id (or row) in each Step. Each step, the loop also run through a submit button that can activate a controller function (linket to that id (or row)). This function therefore returns a `message()`(specific to the exact id or row).

What I want is to get the individual message from each step to be presented just under `echo $something`.
However my problem is that I get the last message from the whole loop presented inside each step (not individual).

Hope I am somewhat just a bit clear !

Comment: Show us your code.

Comment: show us your actual code

Comment: Put your code in the question!

Answer (score 0):

If you need to use the individual records outside the `while` loop, try:

```
$something .= $row['whatever'];

echo $something.
```

Notice the `.`, that's for concatenation.